# How to link a button to a textbox?

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox and several buttons. When the textbox is focused and `<Enter>` key is pressed I want a particular button to run.
How can I do that?

My textbox:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPost" CssClass="TxtPost" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server">
 </asp:TextBox>
```

My buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="Btn1" runat="server" Text="" />
<asp:Button ID="Btn2" runat="server" Text="" />
<asp:Button ID="Btn3" runat="server" Text="" />
```

When `#TxtPost` is focused and `<enter>` is pressed `#Btn2` should run. Ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: you need an autopostback=true in the textbox, then you need an onkeypress event, that will check if the key was the enter key, if so do what ever you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the field and button in a `Panel` and use the `DefaultButton` property.

For example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Btn1">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPost" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Btn1" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```